# Hadamard-like complex variable substitution

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

\begin{align}
\frac\pi a &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dxdye^{-a(x^2+y^2)}\\
\tag{1}&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dxdye^{-a(x+iy)(x-iy)}
\end{align}

So far so good. Now introduce a complex variable $z$ and its conjugate $z^*$ such that

$$
x = \frac{z+z^*}{2}, y=\frac{z-z^*}{2i}
$$

I suppose that means $z=x+iy$ and $z=x-iy$.

According to my professor, this means that the Gauss integral $(1)$ becomes

\begin{align}
\tag{2}\frac\pi a &= \frac{1}{2i}\int dzdz^*e^{-azz^*}
\end{align}

I don't understand how to substitute the variables, and from where to where this integral runs.

I tried it like this:

$$
dx=\frac 12(dz+dz^*), dy=\frac 1{2i}(dz-dz^*)\\
dxdy = \frac{1}{4i}(dz^2-{dz^*}^2)
$$

- How can I show that the last term equals $\frac{1}{2i}dzdz^*$?
- What are the limits of the integral $(2)$?

Comment: (2) is exactly the point: over what path is that complex integral being taken? Observe that $\;dxdy=\frac1{2i}dzdz^*\;$ because that number is the value of the Jacobian (with a minus sign, in fact).

Comment: @DonAntonio That's exactly what I do not understand. Why is $dxdy=\frac{1}{2i}dzdz^*$? Over what path is the complex integral being taken?

Answer (score 1):

The substitution you made yields the Jacobian

$$\begin{vmatrix}\cfrac12&\;\;\cfrac12\\\cfrac1{2i}&-\cfrac1{2i}\end{vmatrix}=-\frac1{2i}\implies dxdy=-\frac1{2i}dzdz^*$$

The minus sign is not that relevant here as without a specific integration path, and thus some orientation, it rather is moot.

I can't tell anything about the path taken, but it would seem to be something in $\;\Bbb C\times\Bbb C\;$ . I really don't know.

Comment: I thought the change of variables formula requires us to take the absolute value of the Jacobian?  Although then we wouldn't even get $\frac1{2i}$ so I'm not sure really.

Comment: @tilper Yes, the absolute value of that determinant...in $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ . Here I can't say, but it really doesn't matter if we don't know how is that integral defined to begin with.

Comment: Yeah, I looked up the formula and it's all about $\Bbb{R}^n$.  I would guess it wouldn't be different in the complex realm because $\Bbb{C}^n$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^{2n}$, or so I thought..  I've been working on an answer that I'm not sure about, but pretty much as sure as I can be given the information we have.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a guess about the path of the integral? My professor wrote it like it's a clear thing.

Comment: Perhaps closing up the unit circle , as in the original real integral it was over the whole real plane. But I'm not in my element here: I don't know this stuff.

Comment: is the path really that relevant? i mean the function to be integrated is holomorphic in both variables and both contours can be deformed to the real line anyway

Comment: @tired What "both contours"? I can't see even one.

Comment: i mean the limiting values of the original integral will induce start/end points in the complex plane, right?

Comment: @tired I've no idea whatsoever how to do that...